# Replace .dds to .png?

Tags: php, replace

I am looking for an way to replace `.dds` to `.png` with `php`.

The reason is this every images is automaticly inserted into the database with the extension `.dds` the `.dds` is an format that the game uses to render its images so i cant replace this.

So what i do is fetch the icons from the database and then the file name must be changed to `.png` before i insert it into an other database.

I have tried it with `preg_replace` but i need some help on how to set it up.

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far?

Comment: Are you sure just replacing the file name will do anything? Don't the images themselves need to be converted from DDS to PNG format?

Answer (score 2):

```
$str = str_replace('.dds', '.png', $mystring);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think replacing extension from DDS to PNG is enought. I think you should rather convert from DDS to PNG:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://server.com/image.dds';
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://api.rest7.com/v1/image_convert.php?url=' . $url . '&format=png'));

if (@$data->success !== 1)
{
    die('Failed');
}
$image = file_get_contents($data->file);
file_put_contents('rendered_page.png', $image);
```